# Can I use Swift 2.3 frameworks in a Swift 3 project?

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, swift3

In my project I migrated all my private swift 2.3 files to swift 3. I would like to use my legacy frameworks written in swift 2.3 until they have a swift 3 version.

I tried to add "Use Legacy Swift Version = Yes". Clear/Build my project but I have still some trouble and xCode ask me to migrate my frameworks to swift 3 (which is just not possible because they are libraries)....

How can I continue to use my 2.3 libraries?

Comment: You can't mix swift 2.3 with swift 3. at least not yet.

Comment: So what can I do to continue to develop on my project?

Comment: I guess you can continue using swift 2.3 for the entire project until those frameworks are updated.

Comment: Many frameworks provide both Swift 2 and 3 renditions, but it's not always obvious. You might want to check to see if there is a Swift 3 branch for the library in question. But, like Sam said, if one of the libraries in question doesn't yet provide a Swift 3 rendition, you can just keep your project in Swift 2.3.

Comment: Ok, cool !! And how can I force xcode to stay in 2.3?

Comment: You just use the "Use Legacy Swift Version" feature that you mention, and if it asks you to convert anything, just decline.

Answer (score 1):

You cay try using this:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
    end
  end
end
```

Note that this will set all of your targets to swift 2.3. If you want one specific, you can do something like that:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    if target.pod_name == 'DesiredPod'
      target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I got an error on target.pod_name, but target.name works

Answer (score 0):

You can set **Build Settings->Swift Compiler - Version-> Use Legacy Swift Language Version** for **Yes**[image]