# Using Swift 3 in Xcode 10.2 - Command /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My goal is to get the new Xcode 10.2 compile and run our projects that are build using Swift 3 and 4.2 (some cocoapods too) and since Xcode 10.2 comes with Swift 5, an unsupported swift error came up when trying to run the projects out of the box (this is expected):

[image]

The solution here is to use an older toolchain as stated on blogs like [this](https://medium.com/xcblog/switching-swift-versions-inside-xcode-using-toolchains-755b28831c43), which i did.

[image]

All good so far. However, after installing the Swift 3 toolchain from [Swift.org](https://swift.org/download/#releases), compiling the project will bring the following error:

> Command
>   /Library/Developer/Toolchains/swift-3.0-RELEASE.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc
>   failed with exit code 1

[image]

I already deleted Derived Data folder, cleanup pods ([my podfile](https://pastebin.com/JPPkde5S)) and reinstalled them, restarted Xcode and Mac multiple times.

Running `xcrun -f swift` and `swift --version` will indeed print the correct swift 3.0 toolchain

[image]

Yes, I know I could just stay with Xcode 10.1 and don't have these issues. Code migration to Swift 4 is also an option but we don't have the time at hand for now so I'm trying to workout this walkaround.

Please help me to resolve this issue, I'm completely stuck. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to update Xcode 10.2  also Migrate your Swift version to 4x or 5

Comment: @GovindhaRaj yes, that's the obvious thing but for a project of that size, it will take months. in the meantime i'm looking for a walkaround, if it exists. thanks!

Comment: It won't take months, no matter the size: either it's a big product and there are many qualified devs around to help with the migration, or it's a medium size product and you're alone but experimented. Swift 3 MUST be abandoned right away. Use the Swift migration assistant and Stack Overflow, and in a couple of days you're done.

Comment: @Cœur it is not only our code that needs updated, but also the bindings with the used pods. we are using multiple pods (including almofire, realm and rxswift) which changed drastically so a lot have to be done to even compile the project. at some point we'll get there anyway, no doubt, but i'm trying to win some time as our backlog is heavy at the moment

Comment: Then, Xcode 10.1 is the fastest option: I had that same issue today on a server, and I solved it with an `xcode-select` to the older version of Xcode and CI server got fixed in just a couple of minutes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Swift 5 to build targets that are written in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205276/can-i-use-swift-5-to-build-targets-that-are-written-in-swift-3)

Comment: @Cœur not really a duplicate, my question is about using a swift 3 toolchain on xcode 10.2, not asking about swift 5 being compatible with swift 3

Comment: If the project is that important why do you wait until the *point of no return*?? Swift 4 was released in September 2017 so you  had 18 *months* to update. Updating from Swift 3 to Swift 4 is not that hard. You can have multiple Xcode versions in the Applications folder so keep 10.1 to maintain your project.

Answer (score 5):

[Xcode10.2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_release_notes/swift_5_release_notes_for_xcode_10_2?preferredLanguage=occ)

> Swift 5 no longer supports the Swift 3 Package.swift tools-version.
>   Packages still on the Swift 3 Package.swift tools-version should
>   update to a newer tools-version. (41974124)

[Swift 5.0](https://swift.org/blog/5-0-release-process/)

> Source Compatibility As with Swift 4.2, the vast majority of sources
>   that built with the Swift 4.2 compiler should compile with the Swift
>   5.0 compiler.
>
> However, the Swift 3 compatibility mode will not be supported in the
>   Swift 5 compiler. Swift 4.2 is the last release of Swift to support
>   Swift 3 mode. There are important changes to both the surface of the
>   language and the interior of its implementation in the releases
>   following Swift 3 that will be the basis of future (and lasting)
>   source and binary stability.

Comment: indeed, there is no support out of the box. but in the same way you could use swift 5 in xcode 10.1 by using its toolchain, i'm looking at the same approach here, but backwards (https://learningswift.brightdigit.com/swift-5-0-xcode-10-1/)

Comment: Need to explore more. Not sure what you are looking is possible

Answer (score 3):

Using **Swift 4.2.1** toolchain work for me.

But https://swift.org/download/#using-downloads tips:

> To submit to the App Store you must build your app using the version of Swift that comes included within Xcode.

Upload to apple connect probably reject by apple.